# MySQL Deadlock reason

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I cannot understand what seems to be the reason of the following MySQL Deadlock.

That part of the code (PHP Laravel) is executed dozens of times each day but it usually fails 2 times every one/two days, but not consistently.
During that operation in one transaction a record is updated in 3 to 5 tables (depending on the scenario).

I have also deployed this app in a few other servers (9+ months running) and it has never failed. The only difference with this deployment is that I have setup [circular replication](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/circular-replication-in-mysql) to another MySQL database in the same LAN. The circular replication does not break when this error occurs.

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2021-12-06 14:03:10 0x7f58ffce1700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 10412119, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 5414250, OS thread handle 140018114578176, query id 201369357 localhost 127.0.0.1 homestead updating
update `customers` set `sales_amount` = '565461.74000049', `collected_amount` = '565461.74000049', `customers`.`updated_at` = '2021-12-06 14:03:10' where `id` = 1

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 54101 page no 4 n bits 168 index PRIMARY of table `parking`.`customers` trx id 10412119 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 24; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 0000009ee052; asc      R;;
2: len 7; hex 020000021a20b3; asc        ;;
3: len 30; hex cea0ceb5cf81ceb9cf83cf84ceb1cf83ceb9ceb1cebacf8ccf8220cea0ce; asc                               ; (total 41 bytes);
4: SQL NULL;
5: SQL NULL;
6: SQL NULL;
7: SQL NULL;
8: len 8; hex ae47e17aab412141; asc  G z A!A;;
9: len 8; hex ae47e17aab412141; asc  G z A!A;;
10: SQL NULL;
11: SQL NULL;
12: SQL NULL;
13: SQL NULL;
14: SQL NULL;
15: len 8; hex ce97ce9cce95cea1; asc         ;;
16: len 4; hex 5f19757a; asc _ uz;;
17: len 4; hex 61adfbfd; asc a   ;;
18: SQL NULL;
19: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
20: len 4; hex 00000013; asc     ;;
21: SQL NULL;
22: SQL NULL;
23: len 8; hex 0000000000000000; asc         ;;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 54101 page no 4 n bits 168 index PRIMARY of table `parking`.`customers` trx id 10412119 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 24; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 0000009ee052; asc      R;;
2: len 7; hex 020000021a20b3; asc        ;;
3: len 30; hex cea0ceb5cf81ceb9cf83cf84ceb1cf83ceb9ceb1cebacf8ccf8220cea0ce; asc                               ; (total 41 bytes);
4: SQL NULL;
5: SQL NULL;
6: SQL NULL;
7: SQL NULL;
8: len 8; hex ae47e17aab412141; asc  G z A!A;;
9: len 8; hex ae47e17aab412141; asc  G z A!A;;
10: SQL NULL;
11: SQL NULL;
12: SQL NULL;
13: SQL NULL;
14: SQL NULL;
15: len 8; hex ce97ce9cce95cea1; asc         ;;
16: len 4; hex 5f19757a; asc _ uz;;
17: len 4; hex 61adfbfd; asc a   ;;
18: SQL NULL;
19: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
20: len 4; hex 00000013; asc     ;;
21: SQL NULL;
22: SQL NULL;
23: len 8; hex 0000000000000000; asc         ;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 10412118, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 17 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 8 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 5414252, OS thread handle 140020162307840, query id 201369360 localhost 127.0.0.1 homestead updating
update `customers` set `sales_amount` = '565463.94000049', `collected_amount` = '565463.94000049', `updated_by` = 7, `customers`.`updated_at` = '2021-12-06 14:03:10' where `id` = 1

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 54101 page no 4 n bits 168 index PRIMARY of table `parking`.`customers` trx id 10412118 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 24; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 0000009ee052; asc      R;;
2: len 7; hex 020000021a20b3; asc        ;;
3: len 30; hex cea0ceb5cf81ceb9cf83cf84ceb1cf83ceb9ceb1cebacf8ccf8220cea0ce; asc                               ; (total 41 bytes);
4: SQL NULL;
5: SQL NULL;
6: SQL NULL;
7: SQL NULL;
8: len 8; hex ae47e17aab412141; asc  G z A!A;;
9: len 8; hex ae47e17aab412141; asc  G z A!A;;
10: SQL NULL;
11: SQL NULL;
12: SQL NULL;
13: SQL NULL;
14: SQL NULL;
15: len 8; hex ce97ce9cce95cea1; asc         ;;
16: len 4; hex 5f19757a; asc _ uz;;
17: len 4; hex 61adfbfd; asc a   ;;
18: SQL NULL;
19: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
20: len 4; hex 00000013; asc     ;;
21: SQL NULL;
22: SQL NULL;
23: len 8; hex 0000000000000000; asc         ;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 54101 page no 4 n bits 168 index PRIMARY of table `parking`.`customers` trx id 10412118 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 24; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 0000009ee052; asc      R;;
2: len 7; hex 020000021a20b3; asc        ;;
3: len 30; hex cea0ceb5cf81ceb9cf83cf84ceb1cf83ceb9ceb1cebacf8ccf8220cea0ce; asc                               ; (total 41 bytes);
4: SQL NULL;
5: SQL NULL;
6: SQL NULL;
7: SQL NULL;
8: len 8; hex ae47e17aab412141; asc  G z A!A;;
9: len 8; hex ae47e17aab412141; asc  G z A!A;;
10: SQL NULL;
11: SQL NULL;
12: SQL NULL;
13: SQL NULL;
14: SQL NULL;
15: len 8; hex ce97ce9cce95cea1; asc         ;;
16: len 4; hex 5f19757a; asc _ uz;;
17: len 4; hex 61adfbfd; asc a   ;;
18: SQL NULL;
19: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
20: len 4; hex 00000013; asc     ;;
21: SQL NULL;
22: SQL NULL;
23: len 8; hex 0000000000000000; asc         ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
------------
```

Can you understand what is the reason for the deadlock? Are there any workarounds I could try?
*Thank you*

**EDIT**

I still do not know what is the reason for failing but this workaround is accepted for me.

I have wrapped that transaction in a try-catch loop which retries 5 times. The error still occurs but with the second attempt it succeeds.

Comment: It is really important to have error handling for your transactions and a deadlock is not an unusual scenario to have to handle. A small pause before rerunning your transaction is a fairly typical solution. I am a little confused by that deadlock log entry as it suggests that both transactions hold the same lock but in different modes which shouldn't be possible. Are these queries being run by a multithreaded batch process? It would help if you could include the full set of queries in each tx.

Comment: @nnichols Indeed it is possible for a special kind of customer to pay via two channels concurrently (this is normal) so each http request is a different process. Maybe there are other requests (besides payment) using the same customer. Even if I managed to collect the full set of queries running in that tx I do not know what is the other process actually doing because it succeeds so it is not logged anywhere. Is there a way to get that info through mysql?

Comment: I cannot see how anyone is going to be able to help you without full details of the two transactions. Without knowing more my only suggestion would be to move the summary data to its own table to make the tx as small and fast as possible. Then you could serialize your transactions with table-level locks on the summary table. Obviously this would cause blocking but not deadlocks.

Comment: @nnichols The payment procedures must execute quickly so that solution is not acceptable. To collect all the queries in the transactions and intercept the business operations that collide would be time consuming to implement (even though necessary). Attempting multiple times is a viable workaround. Thank you for your time and your effort to help me.